# pyspark randomsplit give StackOverflowError

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

"data" here is a pyspark dataframe contains much more negative samples than positive samples. I tried to down sample the negative samples to (e.g.) 20%. And I found randomSplit method step continuing gave java.lang.StackOverflowError. Here is my down sample code:

```
def downsample(data,percent=0.2):
    datap = data.filter(data.label==1)  # positive samples
    datan = data.filter(data.label==0)  # negative samples
    (data1,_) = datan.randomSplit([percent,1-percent]) # random split the data
    ndata = datap.unionAll(data1)  # new training dataset
    return ndata
```

datan.randomSplit will give me stackoverflow error. The data set is around 2 GB. I use amazon 5 nodes (1 master node,4 slave nodes) in the emr clusters, all of them are c4.xlarge. I believe it has enough memory, because I can finish training the data without downsampling. Only when I trying to downsampling, it will gave me stackoverflow error. How should I fix it? Thank you!